# Alternative SQL Nested while Loop to Recursive / Non Loop for Row by Row Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been looking for the alternative solution for nested while loop in SQL.

Need to update a column in a table like the code below. And could not find a better solution for performance enhancement for this. Since I've been updating a large scale of records and the performance for the update is very slow.

The code below is having two iteration in while loop.
The first iteration is getting the information for the variables to be save in a variable for the replacement of new values in the column(that has NVARCHAR(MAX)) for table 2.

For the second iteration it will replace all "old key" to "new key" value of every "KeyId=" instance and will loop through all of the table 2 table.

After the loop in table 2 is finish it will loop again to Table 1 to iterate and change again the values on table 2 column.

Need to find alternative set of solution for this since there are two while loop in the sql.

Hoping for your kind answers for this solution. Since I'm not an expert in SQL.

Thanks in advance.

---

```
DECLARE @StartId_Tbl1 AS INT
DECLARE @EndId_Tbl1 AS INT
DECLARE @CurrentId_Tbl1 AS INT
DECLARE @OldKey AS Varchar(10)
DECLARE @NewKey AS Varchar(10)

DECLARE @StartId_Tbl2 AS INT
DECLARE @EndId_Tbl2 AS INT
DECLARE @CurrentId_Tbl2 AS INT

SELECT @StartId_Tbl1 = MIN([Id]), @EndId_Tbl1 = MAX([Id]) FROM  [dbo].[Tbl1] 
SET @CurrentId_Tbl1 = @StartId_Tbl1

SELECT @StartId_Tbl2 = MIN([Id]), @EndId_Tbl2 = MAX([Id]) FROM  [dbo].[Tbl2] 
SET @CurrentId_Tbl2 = @StartId_Tbl2

WHILE(@CurrentId_Tbl1 <= @EndId_Tbl1)

BEGIN
    SELECT @OldKey = [OldName], @NewKey = [NewName] FROM  [dbo].[Tbl1]
    Where Id = @CurrentId_Tbl1

    WHILE(@CurrentId_Tbl2 <= @EndId_Tbl2)
        BEGIN

            UPDATE [dbo].[Tbl2] 
            SET LongDescription = REPLACE(LongDescription, ''KeyId="'' + @OldKey + ''"'',  ''KeyId="'' + @NewKey)
            WHERE Id = @CurrentId_Tbl2

            SET @CurrentId_Tbl2 = @CurrentId_Tbl2 + 1
        END
    
    SET @CurrentId_Tbl1 = @CurrentId_Tbl1 + 1
END
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code is supposed to be doing.  Don't make readers guess at this information.

Comment: If you're using a loop on SQL you are almost certainly doing it wrong. SQL is a set based language, and a loop is the complete opposite of that. Why not just update the rows in one statement? If you want to batch, that's fine, but a well desiged database can handle millions of updates in a single statement and would do it significantly faster than an RBAR process.

Comment: Hi Larnu, thanks for this. There are different kinds of keys that can be found in a single column value "LongDescription" that's why I need to iterate to the first table then get the values for replacement to the second table column.

Comment: @PeterReyes you can most likely compute the key values in a sub-query or similar to build a complete dataset for a single update statement... Which we would be able to determine for sure once you provide sample data and desired results as Gordon has already requested. Help us to help you, provide a [mre] of the complete problem, not just code which doesn't give us the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what your code appears to do, you could try something like this

```
update t2
set LongDescription = replace(t2.LongDescription, 
                              'KeyId="' + t1.[OldName] + '"',
                              'KeyId="' + t1.[NewName] + '"')
from [dbo].[Tbl2] t2
     join [dbo].[Tbl1] t1 on t2.Id=t1.Id;
```